# Redirect my domain

Tags: cross-domain, hosting

I need to redirect my domain from MyHosting to Godaddy. Currently my client website is maintain in MyHosting , now they need to change their website to Godaddy. Could you please help me to redirect the domain.

Sorry my English is bad. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score -2):

Please use this Link to redirect from one domain to another ......
[enter link description here](https://www.godaddy.com/help/manually-forwarding-or-masking-your-domain-name-422)

To Forward or Mask Your Domain Name

> 1. Log in to your Account Manager.
> 2. Next to Domains, click Manage.
> 3. Select the domain names you want to forward.
> 4. You cannot forward or mask .tk, .dk or .ch domain names.

Click Forward, and then select Forwarding Domains.
Click Add Forwarding.

Select http:// or https:// as your Forward to option. For more information, see HTTP vs. HTTPS.
Enter the URL you want to forward your domain name to.
Select your Redirect type
301 (Permanent) — Redirects to the site you specified in the Forward To field using a "301 Moved Permanently" HTTP response. The HTTP 301 response code tells user-agents (including search engines) that the location has permanently moved.
302 (Temporary) — Redirects to the site you specified in the Forward To field using a "302 Found" HTTP response. The HTTP 302 response code tells user-agents (including search engines) that the location has temporarily moved.
Select your Forward settings
Forward only — Forwards the domain without masking.
Forward with Masking — Prevents the forwarded domain name URL from displaying in the browser's address bar, and lets you enter Meta Tags for search engine crawlers in the following fields:
Title — Displays at the top of the browser window and in search results.
Description — A short description of your website to display in search engine results.
Keyword — A list of comma-separated keywords that describes the content and purpose of your website.
Masking is incompatible with some sites that use https://, i.e. SSL certificates.

To automatically update your nameservers to accommodate your forwarding changes, check Update my DNS setting to support this change.
Click Add, and then click Save.
To Forward Your Domain Name Without Masking

> 1. Log in to your Account Manager.
> 2. Next to Domains, click Manage.
> 3. Select the domain names you want to forward.
> 4. Next to Forwarding, click Manage.
> 5. Click Update Forwarding.
> 6. Select Forward Only from the Forward Settings menu.
> 7. Click Edit.

NOTE: Forwarded domain names can take up to 24-48 hours to activate.

To Remove Masking From Your Domain Name

> 1. Log in to your Account Manager.
> 2. Next to Domains, click Manage.
> 3. Select the domain names to modify.
> 4. Click Forward, and then select Forwarding Domains.
> 5. Click Update Forwarding.
> 6. From the Forward settings pull down menu select the option for Forward Only.
> 7. Click Edit.
> 8. Click Save.

Comment: @MartinZabel, Thanks for your suggestion. :)